# OpenCV C++ error (cvCaptureFromCAM())

Tags: c++, opencv

I was following a tutorial on web for an OpenCV library, and have a problem actually on an early stage. After declaring needed variables to capture a picture from a webcam with the help of "cvCaptureFromCAM(0)" function. 
After compiling it gives me:
 error: ‘p_capWebcam’ was not declared in this scope

I have seen a plenty of problems with "was not declared in this scope" errors but didn't find a solution..

Thank you

```
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>
#include <opencv/cvaux.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

CvSize size640x480 = cvSize(640, 480); 

CvCapture* p_camWebcam;  

IplImage* p_imgOriginal; 
IplImage* p_imgProcessed;

CvMemStorage* p_strStorage; 

CvSeq* p_seqCircles;     

float* p_fltXYReadius;    

int i;                    
char charCheckForEscKey;   



p_camWebcam = cvCaptureFromCAM(0); 

if(p_capWebcam == NULL) {   
printf("error: capture is NULL \n");
getchar();  
return(-1); 
}
}
```

Comment: You Post this with the c++ tag, however your code and the openCV functions you are using seem more like c.

Comment: I haven't used OpenCV for a long while. And I'm never an expert on OpenCV. But I guess the problem lies in the CvMemStorage part. Maybe you should use a *cvCreateMemStorage* function. Just a hint. I'm not sure it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> p_ca***m***Webcam = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
>
> if(p_ca***p***Webcam == NULL) {

Seriously?

Comment: what are you trying to say ?

Comment: @berak I'm saying that the error is caused by a simple typo which is so obvious that I wonder how OP could miss it when (1) writing it, (2) checking it again after the error occurred, (3) posting it to SO.

Comment: waa, ok, missed it, too ;(